# How can I dynamically set the context-root in Payara Micro?

Tags: docker, jakarta-ee, glassfish, payara-micro

I am building a docker image for an application that is deployed to several environments. The context-root needs to be different for some of these environments.

Until now I used [payara/server-full](https://hub.docker.com/r/payara/server-full/) as the base image but I want to switch to the lightweight [payara/micro](https://hub.docker.com/r/payara/micro/) image.

In the former I was able to set the context-root using:

```
${PAYARA_PATH}/generate_deploy_commands.sh --contextroot "${CONTEXT_ROOT}"
```

This means I was able to dynamically configure the context root when starting a docker container using an environment variable.

I failed to find a similar option for payara micro deployments. As a fallback I tried creating a glassfish-web.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    <context-root>__CONTEXT_ROOT__</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

During container start up (before starting payara micro) I then replaced `__CONTEXT_ROOT__` with the value of the environment variable (e.g. 'api/v1') and added it to the WEB-INF directory of the var file.

It seems payara micro doesn't use the context-root specification of that config file. The application is still deployed based on the file name of the '.war'. I could rename the '.war' based on the environment variable but that doesn't allow any 'slashes'/nested paths. Or is there a way to do that?

I'm running out of ideas and didn't find any solutions in similar questions and bugs. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so since I didn't seem to find a built-in way to achieve this I basically copied the behavior of the server-full docker image and it worked.

In detail:

1. copied the [generate_deploy_commands.sh](https://github.com/payara/docker-payaraserver-full/blob/master/generate_deploy_commands.sh) script to my build folder
2. added the script to the container during build and making it executable
3. added env var `ENV POSTBOOT_COMMANDS postboot.txt` and `ENV CONTEXT_ROOT api`
4. ran `${PAYARA_PATH}/generate_deploy_commands.sh --contextroot "${CONTEXT_ROOT}"` as part of docker RUN, but before actually starting payara
5. started payara with --postbootcommandfile $POSTBOOT_COMMANDS
6. now we can set context root using -e CONTEXT_ROOT=api/v1 when running the docker container

I hope this helps others looking for a solution.

Comment: This is for now the only way to set a context root in Payara Micro. In general, asadmin commands with `--postbootcommandfile` is a proper way of doing something that isn't available with command line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little late but according to [this](https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/documentation/payara-server/server-configuration/var-substitution/usage-of-variables.html) you can do "special" environment expansion in `glassfish-web.xml` ie. if you put this in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN"
  "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>${ENV=CONTEXT_ROOT}</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

That expands to your wanted context-root. I tested with payara-micro 5.183, but according to the documentation, you should be good to go from as of middle of may 2017.

However if you call your war `ROOT.war` as I did first, you will encounter problems. I can't really tell why but that overrides `glassfish-web.xml`'s context-root, and puts it in the root.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, the recent Payara Micro 5.182 doesn't support any option to specify the contextRoot. It's always derived from the name of the WAR file.

The only way to deploy an application to a custom context root with Payara Micro 5.182 is to deploy the application using the asadmin deploy command in a `--postbootcommandfile`, which allows specifying all deployment properties, including the context root. See https://docs.payara.fish/documentation/payara-micro/asadmin/pre-and-post-boot-scripts.html for documentation of usage.

Comment: okay, so that's what I thought. Thanks for answering. I ended up copying the behavior of the server-full image, as you can see in the answer I wrote.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. I completely forgot that applications can also be deployed with a postboot command script :)

Answer (score 0):

This can now be achieved by using DEPLOY_PROPS --contextroot=/api for example.

See [here](https://github.com/payara/docker-payaraserver-full/blob/master/bin/init_1_generate_deploy_commands.sh) where the env variable is used.